# Menu flickering with each refresh on Google Chrome

Tags: menus

I am completely at a loss with how to fix this issue and am hoping someone more knowledgeable than me can provide some insight.

At random, my website [jaci.moe](http://jaci.moe) has started to have some issues with the menu flickering on each refresh. The issue does not seem to occur (or at least it does to a less noticeable degree) in both Safari and Firefox. I have tried turning off plugins to isolate it and removed my custom CCS to see if that was the culprit. Neither turned up with any solutions.

Would be so grateful for any insight someone can provide! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be a case of [flash of un-styled text](https://css-tricks.com/fout-foit-foft/) as you are using "Archivo Medium" from Google Web Fonts for your menu.

There is a CSS property [font-display](https://css-tricks.com/font-display-masses/) which would help in your case, however the Google Webfonts don't use this currently. There's an [issue which raises this on GitHub](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/358).

There are a few workarounds, which would be better explored on StackOverflow (as this isn't a Wordpress issue), but you could take a [look at this article](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-avoid-fout-by-adding-a-web-font-preloader--webdesign-8287) from TutsPlus. It makes use of the TypeKit [webfontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look. Played with it a little and that certainly takes care of the issue. Many thanks!!